# How to open a command prompt window in ruby script and have an interactive session

Tags: ruby, windows

I have a requirement where i need to open command prompt and run a bat file, this bat file will ask for the user to enter a choice 2 to 3 times, how to automate this in ruby in windows.

Am able to open command prompt using

```
system("start cmd.exe")
```

After this I need to change directory and then i need to run the file present in `c://temp//dat.bat`, through ruby script.

Please let me know how to automate all these operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd_line = "cmd.exe /c \"cd #{directory}&&#{bat_file}\""
system(cmd_line) # if you're not interested in the output
```

Should do it.

Comment: hey, after running the bat_file its asking for the input, how to provide that? I need to open two such command prompt and run a bat file in both of them and enter the input alternatively.

Comment: My requirement is something like, open two command prompt window and run a bat_file in both of them one after the other and enter input in both of them to establish a connection, and then send the messages from one window.

Comment: What do you mean by "establish a connection, and then send the messages from one window"?